Конфигурация asp.net Identity под существующую базу данных
На проекте мигрировалась база данных, которая когда-то использовалась с asp.net Identity. Иными словами, подход Database First. В базе данных уже существуют все необходимые колонки, которые предоставляет сам asp.net Identity.

Я сделал partial класс для AspNetUser1, которые наследуется от IdentityUser и, аналогично, для AspNetRole1:
public partial class AspNetUser1 : IdentityUser { }
public partial class AspNetRole1 : IdentityRole { }

Во второй части partial класса находятся связи с другими таблицами. Для контекста несколько вариантов:


public partial class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AspNetUser1>



public partial class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AspNetUser1, AspNetRole1, string>



public partial class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AspNetUser1, IdentityRole, string>



Конфигурация самого asp.net Identity выглядит вот так:
services.AddIdentity<AspNetUser1, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // ...
}

Проблема заключается в том, что при запуске проекта получаю ошибку:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.'

То есть, ругается вообще на AspNetUserLogin. Тут стоит уточнить, что таблица не изменялась и имеет вид, которые предоставляется сам asp.net Identity. Проблема заключается скорее всего в конфигурации это таблицы, а именно, что Identity требует от неё primary key типа string:
public partial class AspNetUserLoginConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AspNetUserLogin>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AspNetUserLogin> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });

        // ...
    }
}

Как говорил ранее, это старая БД, которая писалась под asp.net Identity, но сама конфигурация является auto generate кодом, который регулярно перегенерывается. Как вообще это всё лечить?
UPD:
Сам AspNetUserLogin выглядит вот так:

public partial class AspNetUserLogin
{
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
public string ProviderKey { get; set; }

public string ProviderDisplayName { get; set; }

public string UserId { get; set; }

public virtual AspNetUser1 User { get; set; }

}

И так же да, я пробовал наследовать его от IdentityUserLogin, но это не дали вообще никаких результатов. Как создать оптимальную конфигурацию, что бы оно хотя бы запустилось?


Изменить схему базы под требования кода.



Изменить код под требования базы, т.е. как вариант отказаться от AddEntityFrameworkStores()


@4per, зачем отказываться от AddEntityFrameworkStores?

а зачем не отказываться? наверное можно сделать прокладку, но зачем?

@4per, наверное, если бы в доках майков это было бы нормально описано, я бы и отказался бы. Наверное, если бы мне не нужно было использовать этот кусок ..., я бы сделал всё ручками и всё работало бы. Наверное, если я пишу сюда, то не очень понял как работает с этим куском ... Но зачем же я сюда мог написать этот вопрос? Наверное, сидел я на работе, и мне скучно стало
